# Optimization of SQL query with multiple unions

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Does anybody know how to make this query a bit shorter? The problem, and reason why I am asking this is is that it takes a long time to process the query because the query returns over 16K records.

```
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem,
         1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
         s.osnov*s.kol_dok AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija*s.kol_dok AS premija 
     FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pol s 
     WHERE p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet+ AND s.vs='SO' AND s.premija<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem, 
        1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija 
     FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pol s 
     WHERE p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet AND s.vs='DO' AND s.premija<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem, 
        1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, s.stopa, -s.premija AS premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pol s 
    WHERE p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet AND s.vs='PO' AND s.premija<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem, 
         1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
         s.osnov*s.kol_dok AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija*s.kol_dok AS premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pril s 
    WHERE p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet AND s.vs='SO' AND s.premija<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem, 
        1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pril s 
    WHERE p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet AND s.vs='DO' AND s.premija<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem, 
        1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, s.stopa, -s.premija AS premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pril s 
    WHERE p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet AND s.vs='PO' AND s.premija<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, q.nac_prem, 
        0 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.skup_os q, osiguranje.st_pol s 
    WHERE p.proizvod=q.sifra AND p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet AND s.vs='DK' AND s.stopa<>0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, q.nac_prem, 
        0 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, -s.stopa AS stopa, s.premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.skup_os q, osiguranje.st_pol s 
    WHERE p.proizvod=q.sifra AND p.broj=s.broj AND 
        XUvjet  AND s.vs='PK' AND s.stopa<>0 
ORDER BY p.broj, gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial
```

XUvjet is a variable that'll be inserted in a C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `s.vs` in WHERE clause you can easily use the IN operator:

```
WHERE s.vs IN ['PK', 'DK', 'PO', ...]
```

For the `gr_red` in SELECT clause you can use the CASE-WHEN operator:

```
SELECT  ' ' AS nac_prem, gr_red =
      CASE
         WHEN s.vs='PK' THEN 0
         WHEN  XUvjet AND s.vs='PO' THEN 1
         ELSE 1
      END,
```

Obviously you can add more logic to the WHEN clause here to make it fit the logic of your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all those Where clauses, like this:

```
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem,
         1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
         s.osnov*s.kol_dok AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija*s.kol_dok AS premija 
     FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pol s 
     WHERE (p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet+ AND s.vs='SO' AND s.premija<>0)
         or(p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet AND s.vs='DO' AND s.premija<>0)
         or (p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet AND s.vs='PO' AND s.premija<>0)
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, ' ' AS nac_prem, 
         1 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
         s.osnov*s.kol_dok AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija*s.kol_dok AS premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.st_pril s 
    WHERE (p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet AND s.vs='SO' AND s.premija<>0)
        or (p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet AND s.vs='DO' AND s.premija<>0)
        or (p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet AND s.vs='PO' AND s.premija<>0)
UNION ALL    
SELECT p.broj, p.mje_osig, p.id_cjen, p.poc_dat, p.ist_dat, q.nac_prem, 
        0 AS gr_red, s.rbr, s.serial, s.vs, s.stat_id, s.naziv, 
        s.osnov AS osnovica, s.stopa, s.premija 
    FROM osiguranje.police_osn p, osiguranje.skup_os q, osiguranje.st_pol s 
    WHERE (p.proizvod=q.sifra AND p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet AND s.vs='DK' AND s.stopa<>0)
        or (p.proizvod=q.sifra AND p.broj=s.broj AND XUvjet  AND s.vs='PK' AND s.stopa<>0)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if you look closely you will see that the 4th SELECT section looks in a different table called st_pril instead of st_pol. But this looks very interesting :)

Comment: @Levidoom - Ah, yes - and I notice now that there is also a third.  You can use this same method but it looks like you will need 3 queries with 2 unions.

Comment: @Levidoom - I updated this solution to include all three table combinations.

Comment: Thanks again, but... (I'm starting to hate the word "but") this method will turn into the original query if you account all the  differences in all the SELECT sections. :(

Comment: @Levidoom - I;m afraid that given the fact each section is a combination of different tables and you're looking to append the results from each section, you will have to use Union this way.

Comment: @Levidoom - Oh, now I see there are subtle differences in the third row of the selects.  Yikes.  I don't think you can shorten it.  Each query is unique and any attempt to move the conditional logic to the Select list would mean Case statements would need to include all of the Where clause logic for each metric.

Comment: well thank you for your time, that is unfortunate. Maybe if i find something I will post as an answer :)